# How to check CRM database size entity wise in Dynamics CRM online?

Tags: dynamics-crm

How can I check how much amount of database size is used by the particular entity? or Is there any way to check data size of an entity in Dynamics CRM online ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not possible without additional actions as far as I know. As a possible workaround you can do following:

1. Ask MS Support to provide you with latest DB of your organization.
2. Restore this DB to some SQL server.
3. Use it for your data-analysis.